# Transfer data from a txt file in Excel book

Tags: c#

Good afternoon. Faced with the problem. There is a task to open a *.txt file in Excel.

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

if (xlApp == null)
{
    TaskDialog.Show("ups", "Where's your Excel?!");
}

Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText
(
    @"C:\newPath\OveralFile.txt", 
    Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
    1,            
    Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
    Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
    true,          
    true,          
    false,         
    false,         
    false,         
    false,         
    Type.Missing,  
    misValue,
    Type.Missing,  
    ".",           
    ","
);

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\newPath\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);


xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);

xlApp.Quit();


Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

After the code book exists, but is empty.
It looks like a text document.

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the delimiter is a tab ?

Comment: Also maybe you missed some fields per `Sub OpenText(Filename As String, [Origin], [StartRow], [DataType], [TextQualifier As XlTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote], [ConsecutiveDelimiter], [Tab], [Semicolon], [Comma], [Space], [Other], [OtherChar], [FieldInfo], [TextVisualLayout], [DecimalSeparator], [ThousandsSeparator], [TrailingMinusNumbers], [Local])` e.g. assume you should have `false` for `OtherChar` (not `misValue`) and something for `TrailingMinusNumbers` and `Local` ?

Comment: yes, i'm sure the separator is a tab. A text document is created programmatically

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not saving the readed workbook, but an empty one. Try to change this line:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\newPath\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
                  misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                  Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, 
                  misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

Into this:

```
xlApp.Workbooks[2].SaveAs(@"C:\newPath\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
                          misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                          Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, 
                          misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

That way you would be saving the new readed workbook.

**Edit**

I've cleaned out your code because you were creating objects not needed and it was leaving Excel processes open. The code should be like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText
    (
    @"C:\newPath\OveralFile.txt",
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
    1,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
    true,
    true,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    Type.Missing,
    misValue,
    Type.Missing,
    ".",
    ","
);

xlApp.Workbooks[1].SaveAs(@"C:\newPath\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
                         misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                         Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                         misValue, misValue);

xlApp.Workbooks[1].Close();

xlApp.Quit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp.Workbooks);

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot